# How can I get name of element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I get name property of HTML element with jQuery?

Comment: some html or even a little more information about the element you want the name of would help us give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Use `.prop()` to get properties, and `.attr()` to get attributes. Don't use `.attr()` to get a property as everyone suggests. We're working with JavaScript here, not HTML markup.

Comment: This should be reopened. Asker should be rewarded for getting to the point and not prefacing with something like "I have this website where..."

Answer (score 262, accepted):

You should use `attr('name')` like this

```
 $('#yourid').attr('name')
```

you should use an id selector, if you use a class selector you encounter problems because a collection is returned

Comment: I'm just getting undefined values when I use this or .prop()

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer attr('name') over prop('name')?

Comment: I used `$(this).attr('name');` on a class selector `$('.jobSelect').change(function() {` and I didn't encounter problems.

Answer (score 18):

To read a property of an object you use `.propertyName` or `["propertyName"]` notation.

This is no different for elements.

```
var name = $('#item')[0].name;
var name = $('#item')[0]["name"];
```

---

If you specifically want to use `jQuery` methods, then you'd use the `.prop()` method.

```
var name = $('#item').prop('name');
```

---

*Please note that attributes and properties are not necessarily the same.*

Comment: i think `prop()` is for boolean properties like `checked` not for attributes

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: `.prop()` is for any property on the DOM element. `.attr()` is a very confused method that has changed its behavior between different releases, sometimes giving you the property, other times the attribute. Either way, there is a distinction between attributes and properties that should be observed by using the proper method.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/u35MG/) that illustrates the distinction between properties and attributes.

Answer (score 11):

```
$('someSelectorForTheElement').attr('name');
```

Comment: you should use an id selector, if you use a class selector you encounter problems because a collection is returned

Comment: id would be most specific yes, but with out their html and the complete lack of detail in the question, it's hard to say what selector they should use.

Comment: Then the important point to mention is it's returning the 1st match's name.

Answer (score 8):

Play around with this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cTSKp/):

**HTML:**

```
<p id="foo" name="bar">Hello, world!</p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    var name = $('#foo').attr('name');

    alert(name);
    console.log(name);
});
```

This uses jQuery's [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to get value for the first element in the matched set.

While not specifically jQuery, the result is shown as an [alert prompt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) and written to the browser's [console](http://davidwalsh.name/firebug-console-log).

Answer (score 3):

```
var name = $('#myElement').attr('name');
```

Answer (score 2):

The method [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) allows getting attribute value of the first element in a jQuery object:

```
$('#myelement').attr('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is also looking for how to get the name of the HTML tag, you can use "**tagName**":
$(this)[0].**tagName**