# jQuery shows "name" instead of "value"

Tags: jquery, checkbox, click

I have a time table with checkbox:

```
<table id="date">
    <tr>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Sun" id="sun" value="0" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Mon" id="mon" value="1" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Tue" id="tue" value="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Wed" id="wed" value="3" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Thu" id="thu" value="4" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Fri" id="fir" value="5" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Sat" id="sat" value="6" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p><span id="dateValue"></span></p>
<button id="dateSave">Add</button>
```

And the jquery part:

```
$(function() {
    function dateValue() {
        var values = [];
        $('#date :checked').each(function () {
            values.push($(this).val());
        });

        $('#dateValue').text(values);
    }

    $(function () {
        $('#dateSave').click(dateValue);
            $('#dateValue').text(values);
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#dateDate input').click(dateValue);
            dateValue();
    });

});
```

When I select the checkbox and click the button, checkbox's "value" will dynamically input to `<span>`, but I want to show checkbox's "name" instead of "value",
if I select checkbox, `<span>` will show "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu"...etc, not "1,2,3,4"...
How to fix my code?

Comment: See how to get name of jQuery element here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852665/how-can-i-get-name-of-element-with-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So use:

```
values.push(this.name); // or $(this).attr('name')
```

Comment: 2 seconds missed from posting the same.. :P

Comment: Thx a lot!! It really helps me :D

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is change your reference to `$(this).val()` to instead ask for `$(this).prop('name'))` when you are pushing into the `values` array.

See my fiddle example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brendanmoore/b5xoynmn/)

Answer (score -1):

try to replace

```
$(this).val()
```

with

```
$(this).attr('value')
```

Comment: The `attr()` function can also be used in this case rather than `prop()`. However, since you are still suggesting @SSP pull the **value** rather than the **name** from the element properties, this will still end up showing the numbers rather than the short day names.